# Django Rest Framework Custom error format

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Hi I have the following dict to be serialised

```
{
    "field_name":"myrole",
    "description":"it has access",
    "status":"active",
    "role":"admin",
    "modules":[
        {
          "module_id":"newid",
          "create":true,
          "read":true,
          "update":true,
          "delete":true
        }
]

}
```

Serializer I'm having now is

```
class ModulerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    module_id = serializers.BooleanField(required=True, allow_null=True)
    delete = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
    read = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    create = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
    update = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)


class RoleValidateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field_name = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=128)
    role = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=128)
    status = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=128)
    modules = serializers.ListField(child=ModulerSerializer())
```

it is producing the error message like below

```
{'field_name': [ErrorDetail(string='Must be a valid boolean.', code='invalid')], 
  'modules': {
          0: {'module_id': [ErrorDetail(string='Must be a valid boolean.', code='invalid')], 
'read': [ErrorDetail(string='A valid integer is required.', code='invalid')]}}}
```

What I'm expecting is to append all error message values in to a single array like below or extracting error message from all nested child object

```
[field_name Must be a valid boolean,module_id Must be a valid boolean, read A valid integer is required.  ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to define your custom exception handler that will be used in any web service call: create a python file (e.g., `handle_exceptions.py`) under your django application, let `app`, and put the logic on it.

For instance:

app/handle_exceptions.py

```py
import copy
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def my_exception_handler(exc, context):
  response = exception_handler(exc, context)

  if response is not None:
    try:
      if isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
        custom_errors = []
        errors = copy.deepcopy(response.data)
        for field, message in errors.items():
          if isinstance(message, dict):
            # process message
            # error_message = '...'
          elif isinstance(message, list):
            # process message
            # error_message = '...'
          elif isinstance(message, str):
            # process message
            # error_message = '...'
          custom_errors.append(error_message)        

        response.data = custom_errors
    except Exception as ex:
      print(str(ex))
    return response
```

To get the str representation of the `ErrorDetail(string='Must be a valid boolean.', code='invalid')` try `str(ErrorDetail(string='Must be a valid boolean.', code='invalid'))`.

Then, go to the your project settings and change the EXCEPTION_HANDLER module of the django rest framework as follows:

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...

    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'app.handle_exceptions.my_exception_handler'
    # 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER':'rest_framework.views.exception_handler',
}
```

The above solution requires the usage of django rest framework package.

Comment: What exactly are you doing to the message if it's a dict? ideally wouldn't you want to return the dict?